# Bing Maps no longer runs KML files ref by mapurl

Tags: kml, bing-maps

One of my Android trip tracking apps stores a KML file on my server and sends the user of the app a URL pointing to the file.

Example:

http://bing.com/maps/default.aspx?mapurl=http://www.deanblakely.com/REST/KML/Timeout2016-03-09084829AM3142016348PMmawardjrgmail.kml

It has been working for several years but now it no longer works displaying a misleading error saying "This content is not available.  It may have been deleted by the author".

So what is going on?  I recall that Google Maps dropped support for KML a year or so ago.  Has Bing done the same?

I have ran links that used to work that don't work now.  I know the links are good.

Regards,

Dean

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your KML URL. When I try and running it in a browser I see an error on your server.

Comment: What kind of an error are you seeing?  I'm just getting that page I describe in my post above.

Comment: When I put http://www.deanblakely.com/REST/KML/Timeout2016-03-09084829AM3142016348PMmawardjrgmail.kml in a browser I get a server error 

[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9693128
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53

Comment: When I put that into I.E. 11 or Edge I get the KML content listed.  In Chrome browser I get the KML file downloaded.  I think both of these are expected results.

Comment: The file wasn't working for me until just now. Every time I tried to load the URL to your file I saw a server error. Looks like the file is available now and loads fine on bing.com